# d3 stacked bar update not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a stacked bar chart made in D3 v5.
https://codepen.io/bental/pen/oMbrjL

I haven't quite got my head around the update pattern, the bars overwrite.

I think I have to grab the inner rects on the update, but I cant quite make this work. I'm sure my misunderstanding and error lies in the plotArea() function

```
function plotArea() {
  const stackedData = d3.stack().keys(keys)(data);
  const layer = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(stackedData);

  layer
    .transition()
    .attr('x', (d) => graphAxes.x(d.data.interval))
    .attr('y', (d) => graphAxes.y(d[1]))
    .attr('height', (d) => graphAxes.y(d[0]) - graphAxes.y(d[1]))
    .attr('width', graphAxes.x.bandwidth());

  layer
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', d => 'data-path type-' + d.key)
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(d => d)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('x', (d) => {
      return graphAxes.x(d.data.interval)
    })
    .attr('y', (d) => graphAxes.y(d[1]))
    .attr('width', graphAxes.x.bandwidth())
    .attr('height', (d) => graphAxes.y(d[0]) - graphAxes.y(d[1]));

  layer.exit()
    .transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) {
      return 30 * i;
    })
    .duration(1500)
    .attr('y', graphAxes.y(0))
    .attr('height', graphDimensions.height - graphAxes.y(0))
    .remove();
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening, but the first thing i noticed is that every time `plotArea()` is called, you are appending a new `<g>` element to the root svg... which is probably not what you want.

Comment: interesting, ill have a play with that

Comment: Is this what you wanted? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/djMbOx?editors=0011, are the bars in the second data plot meant to look like that? Wasn't sure if you werer purely having troubles with the bar overlapping or whether the data wasn't plotting correctly either. If this is correct I'll write up a proper answer with an explanation.

Comment: So I was hoping for the bars to transform into each other, so if there were 2 and then after update 3, only one would appear and the others would remain, maybe change dimensions depending on the data. I'll have a look through your example though It might help

Comment: I like what you've done with the update function, will have a play with that and keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: @BenTaliadoros Good luck :). Btw, I just updated the codepen so that it spawns from the bottom not the top as it was bugging me.

Comment: That's a lot better you're right, I'll certainly use the principles you have introduced as it's a lot better than what i have so far!

Comment: This works for me, i was looking to update the bars rather than kill and redraw, but this works well too. Note I call plotArea() after looping through each node rather than on the start of each transition, this seems to work much better. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working!